# Transpose and drop years

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to paste an object to excel but I am having trouble transposing it to a row and dropping the years. The example is below:

```
c
Out[274]: 
2020      3.000000
2021    323.216667
2022    127.533333
2023      1.500000
2024   -148.000000
2025    -25.083333
2026    -48.133333
2027   -234.033333
2028      0.000000

type(c)
Out[272]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I tried for instance

```
c = c.T
c.transpose()
```

Any help would be dearly appreciated!

Best,
João

Comment: `c=c.reset_index(drop=True)` after that `c.T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to typecast it to a DataFrame before using `transpose`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(c).T
```

Comment: oh! I see! thank you!

any idea on how to drop the years, though?

Comment: If you're trying to work with only the numeric data in your Series, you can just use `c.values` which would return an array. I doubt you can have a `pd.DataFrame` without column names and it's also not recommended.

Comment: please accept my dearest thank you, sir/madam!

Answer (score 1):

You can also transform the Series to a DaataFrame by [`.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and then [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
c.to_frame().T
```

Result:

```
   2020        2021        2022  2023   2024       2025       2026        2027  2028
0   3.0  323.216667  127.533333   1.5 -148.0 -25.083333 -48.133333 -234.033333   0.0
```